# Admin Role not working for certificates and Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

i have been granted the role of admin in apple developer account, i can confirm that by signing to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com. by creating apps from there. but in xcode when i signed in with my account, it shows personal team instead of the linked team, i am unable to get that information of linked developer account. i don't know how to fix that, how to remove that personal team, how to get certificates and profile information of linked account. i searched it online, but some vague solution that does't work for me. any one who has solid solution for this ?

Permission granted to my Apple ID with Admin Role, i was expecting in xcode my Admin role team along with provisioning profile, but got no luck , instead i am getting personal team.

Comment: check this thread  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114018

Comment: @nivritgupta very well explained my problem seems to me with individual account, i am not sure how this can be shifted to organisation account. anyways thanks for the links